# No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, junit, gradle

Estou testando minha aplicação Spring com o JUnit, no entanto esta ocorrendo o erro após colocar a anotação `@EnableJpaRepositories`:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

**Classe de configuração:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Se retirar essa anotação retorna o problema que não encontra uma dependência para a interface do repositório.

**Obs:** A aplicação inicia-se normalmente, esse problema ocorre ao executar os testes, tanto com o Gradle como o JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta:**

O problema estava no teste, precisa da anotação `@MockBean` em cima de um objeto que é uma classe sendo que é um serviço ou repositório, ou seja, é preciso mockar.

**Exemplo:**

```
@MockBean
private UserService userService;
```